# Remove empty level from Box plot with multiple levels

Tags: r

I have a box plot with multiple levels d$a + d$b

```
d = data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,100), a = c("A","A","B","A"), b = c("C","D","C","C") )
boxplot(d$value ~ d$a + d$b, horizontal = TRUE)
```

when you run that code you will see that the B.D combination still shows up but it is empty. How do I remove it?

This is just a toy example. In reality I have 40+ combinations and do not want to remove the blank one by hand.

Comment: @Pascal this is not a duplicate previous questions do not solve for multiple factors

Comment: Do you still see the comment? No.

Comment: would this work fo you `boxplot(value ~ paste(a, b), data=d)`

Answer (score 3):

You can first use `interaction` (together with its `drop` argument) to create a new column of your data.frame, then plot it:

```
d <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,100), a = c("A","A","B","A"), b = c("C","D","C","C"))
d <- within(d, interaction <- interaction(a, b, drop = TRUE))
boxplot(value ~ interaction, data = d, horizontal = TRUE)
```

[image]